# XAML WPF form wont load when runing my script

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, xaml

Hey guys I am getting an error when I try to run my script with my XAML file. Error below. I have also attached the code from my WPF form that I made in visual studio that is causing the error. When I remove this code from my form the script loads the XAML file just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Error:
Exception calling "Load" with "1" argument(s): "Failed to create a 'Click' from the text 'CheckBox1_Click'."

At PATH OF XAML\Script.ps1:30 char:5

$window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

FullyQualifiedErrorId : XamlParseException

```
#Assembly and Sharepoint Connection Code

Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

#Gets user name of the user running the script (Only first and last initial)

$UserName = $env:username.ToCharArray() | Select -First 2

$UserInitials = $UserName -Join ""

#XAML GUI Code

$xamlFile = "Path of XAML file"

#GUI Creation Code

$inputXML = Get-Content $xamlFile -Raw

$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"', '' -replace "x:N", 'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'

[XML]$XAML = $inputXML

#Read XAML

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)


try 
{
    $window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
} 
catch 
{
    Write-Warning $_.Exception
    throw
}

#Create variables based on form control names

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {

    #"trying item $($_.Name)";

    try 
    {
        Set-Variable -Name "var_$($_.Name)" -Value $window.FindName($_.Name) -ErrorAction Stop
    } 
    catch 
    {
        throw
    }

}

Get-Variable var_*

#Code from the click event in my WPF form

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void CheckBox1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CheckBox1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            CheckBox2.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox2.IsChecked = false;
            CheckBox3.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox3.IsChecked = false;
            CheckBox4.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox4.IsChecked = false;
            CheckBox5.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox5.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckBox2.IsEnabled = true;
            CheckBox3.IsEnabled = true;
            CheckBox4.IsEnabled = true;
            CheckBox5.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Apparently the *PresentationFramework* is not available until the *GetTypes* method has been executed, so in order to do that we have to add the `-PassThru` like this: `Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework -PassThru | Out-Null`. 
This also happens when you type a `TAB` for command completion. 
See [discussion](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/16054).

Answer (score 0):

I implement all my control event handling in my PowerShell script rather than using events in the form code.

If you take the code out as you have previously and add an event handler into your PS code as below you should get the solution you are looking for.

```
<ControlVarName>.Add_Click()
{
        if (CheckBox1.IsChecked == true)
        {
            CheckBox2.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox2.IsChecked = false;
            CheckBox3.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox3.IsChecked = false;
            CheckBox4.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox4.IsChecked = false;
            CheckBox5.IsEnabled = false;
            CheckBox5.IsChecked = false;
        }
        else
        {
            CheckBox2.IsEnabled = true;
            CheckBox3.IsEnabled = true;
            CheckBox4.IsEnabled = true;
            CheckBox5.IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
```

You will need to change the form property names to reflect the variable names you gave them in the PS code.

Comment: You sir are amazing! Thank you so much totally solved my issue. I will do this from now on instead of in visual studio makes life so much easier!

Comment: Totally works! Thank you again for all your help. You are amazing!